# RPI kernel version 4.4.11

Tags: kernel

Where can I find the kernel for my RPI2 v4.4.11-v7+

Searched here https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux could not find it

Kind regards, Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to browse github history to go back with commits. Over here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commits/rpi-4.4.y

Here starts first commit with Linux 4.4.11 : https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/544ec5b08d007f184ab97abdbed87e613c8c0b83